# Стилизация SELECT и псеводкласса

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, html-select

Столкнулся с проблемой, стилизую `input` и `select` поля в CSS, проблема вот в чем:

1) Не могу установить позиционирование надписи "Год рождения" по центру.

2) Как подключить внешнюю картинку в пункте `.form_quest label:after { content: ' '}`, чтобы моя кнопка выпадающего меню была другая

```css
.form_quest {
  text-align: center;
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  /* Firefox 18- */
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  /* Firefox 18- */
  /* плавное изменение прозрачности  placeholder-а при фокусе */
}

.form_quest input {
  width: 52rem;
  height: 6rem;
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
  border: none;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  color: #c8c8c8;
}

.form_quest label {
  position: relative;
}

.form_quest label:after {
  content: '>';
  font-size: 2rem;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  right: 2rem;
  top: -1rem;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #c8c8c8;
}

.form_quest select {
  width: 32rem;
  height: 6rem;
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
  border: none;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #c8c8c8;
}

.form_quest ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #c8c8c8;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.form_quest ::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #c8c8c8;
}

.form_quest :-moz-placeholder {
  color: #c8c8c8;
}

.form_quest :-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #c8c8c8;
}

.form_quest ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  text-align: top;
}

.form_quest ::-moz-placeholder {
  text-align: top;
}

.form_quest :-moz-placeholder {
  text-align: top;
}

.form_quest :-ms-input-placeholder {
  text-align: top;
}

.form_quest input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.form_quest input::-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.form_quest input:-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.form_quest input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.form_quest input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.form_quest input:focus::-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.form_quest input:focus:-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.form_quest input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Для сео -->
  <meta name="descritpion" content="">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <!-- Конец сео -->
  <title>One-page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="form_quest">
    <form name="anketa" action="#">
      <input type="text" placeholder="ФИО">
      <label>
          <select name="birth" id="birth" required>
              <option disabled selected="selected">Год рождения</option>
              <option value="1990">1990</option>
              <option value="1991">1991</option>
              <option value="1992">1992</option>
              <option value="1993">1993</option>
              <option value="1990">1994</option>
              <option value="1991">1995</option>
              <option value="1992">1996</option>
              <option value="1993">1997</option>
              <option value="1990">1998</option>
              <option value="1991">1999</option>
          </select>
      </label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Место рождения">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Skype">
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: по второму вопросу `content: url('');`

Comment: для select можно использовать свойство text-indent

Answer (score 1):

1) просто в `css` нельзя текст по центру сделать. 
Простой ваиант 
- наложить див у селекта
сверху(+pointer-events:none) или label для него.
или снизу(если фон селекта можно сделать прозрачным) селекта. 
но нужно отслеживать на js изменение значения и подстановку.
Сложный вариант - полностью сделать кастомизированный селект.

2) фоном в этот псевдоселектор:

```
.form_quest label:after { 
    content: '',
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: url(...) no-repeat top right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Как уже говорил `Artem Gorlachev` нельзя дать какие то свойство `select option` для стилизации местоположения текста.

Можете использовать плагин [jquery](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/) для кастомного стиля `select`.

Ну или же есть только один вариант для центровки текста (`text-indent`), но тогда наверное вы каждый раз должны следить за длиной текста и изменить свойство при каждом выбранном `option`. Но поскольку у вас только две ширины в `option`, начальный и остальные (с одной шириной). То это сделать легче. Просто проверим если не выбран первый то добавим какой то класс `select`-у и там пропишем другой `text-indent`. Все это делаем с помощью `jquery`.

Вот ваш пример:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#birth').on('change', function(){
    if(!$(this).children('option:first-child').is(':selected')){
      $(this).addClass('selected_date');
    }
    else{
      $(this).removeClass('selected_date');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.form_quest {
  text-align: center;
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  /* Firefox 18- */
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  /* Firefox 18- */
  /* плавное изменение прозрачности  placeholder-а при фокусе */
}

.form_quest input {
  width: 52rem;
  height: 6rem;
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
  border: none;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  color: #c8c8c8;
}

.form_quest label {
  position: relative;
}

.form_quest label:after {
  content: '>';
  font-size: 2rem;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  right: 2rem;
  top: -1rem;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #c8c8c8;
}

.form_quest select {
  width: 32rem;
  height: 6rem;
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
  border: none;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #c8c8c8;
}

.form_quest ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #c8c8c8;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.form_quest ::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #c8c8c8;
}

.form_quest :-moz-placeholder {
  color: #c8c8c8;
}

.form_quest :-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #c8c8c8;
}

.form_quest ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  text-align: top;
}

.form_quest ::-moz-placeholder {
  text-align: top;
}

.form_quest :-moz-placeholder {
  text-align: top;
}

.form_quest :-ms-input-placeholder {
  text-align: top;
}

.form_quest input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.form_quest input::-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.form_quest input:-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.form_quest input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.form_quest input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.form_quest input:focus::-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.form_quest input:focus:-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.form_quest input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}
#birth{
  text-indent: 13rem;
}
#birth.selected_date{
  text-indent: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Для сео -->
  <meta name="descritpion" content="">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <!-- Конец сео -->
  <title>One-page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="form_quest">
    <form name="anketa" action="#">
      <input type="text" placeholder="ФИО">
      <label>
        <select name="birth" id="birth" required>
          <option class="opt_disabled" selected="selected">Год рождения</option>
            <option value="1990">1990</option>
            <option value="1991">1991</option>
            <option value="1992">1992</option>
            <option value="1993">1993</option>
            <option value="1990">1994</option>
            <option value="1991">1995</option>
            <option value="1992">1996</option>
            <option value="1993">1997</option>
            <option value="1990">1998</option>
            <option value="1991">1999</option>
          </select></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Место рождения">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Skype">
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```